# Google spreadsheet not add new rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Help me please because i'm stuck.
I'm using these [tutorial](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/) for create leads in my googlesheets.

thats my codeGs

```
var SHEET_NAME = "sheet0637004101";

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 

function doGet(e){
  return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
   return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {

var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
lock.waitLock(30000);  

try {

   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
   var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
   var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
   var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
   var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
   var row = []; 

for (i in headers){
  if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ 
    row.push(new Date());
  } else {
    row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
  }
 }
 sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
 return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} catch(e){

 return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}   finally { 
    lock.releaseLock();
   }
}

function setup() {
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

myform

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
 // variable to hold request
 var request;
 // bind to the submit event of our form
 $("#foo").submit(function(event){
  // abort any pending request
  if (request) {
   request.abort();
  }
  // setup some local variables
  var $form = $(this);
  // let's select and cache all the fields
  var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
  // serialize the data in the form
  var serializedData = $form.serialize();
 
  // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
  // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
  // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
  $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
  $('#result').text('Sending data...');
 
  // fire off the request to /form.php
  request = $.ajax({
   url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyD3AcUuKx7HARMabrer5TzPB4hn6VFcbKDIU36HqZWq6y27J0X/exec",
   type: "get",
   data: serializedData
  });
 
  // callback handler that will be called on success
  request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
   // log a message to the console
   $('#result').html('<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-i4WADh1j-bOR00cyt7XRD_E9H8Q9TE8kC15Bs1z9ro/edit#gid=0"_blank">Success - see Google Sheet</a>');
   console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
  });
 
  // callback handler that will be called on failure
  request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   // log the error to the console
   console.error(
    "The following error occured: "+
    textStatus, errorThrown
   );
  });
 
  // callback handler that will be called regardless
  // if the request failed or succeeded
  request.always(function () {
   // reenable the inputs
   $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
  });
 
  // prevent default posting of form
  event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="foo">

    <p><label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value=""></p>
    <p><label for="comment">Comment:</label><br>
        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="40"></textarea></p>
    <p id="result"><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10tt64TiALYhPMqR2fh9JzkuhxW7oC0rXXPb_pmJ7HAY/edit?usp=sharing" target="_blank">Success - see Google Sheet</a></p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-form" value="Send">

</form>
```

so when i deploy my code and 'Test web app for your latest code.' in codeGs results is {"result":"success","row":5}
when i using link from tutorial, new rows created with my data that send from my test page, but if i'm trying add my link from that created in my codeGs rows not added. But browser anwering first 302 after 200 is ok. Where i'm wrong. Heeeelp me pleease

Comment: [HTTP 302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) response is not an error. It indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header. You can read more about this in [Generic 301 Redirection Script for Google App Engine](https://blog.dantup.com/2010/01/generic-redirection-script-for-google-app-engine/).

Comment: Thank you for answer but code in tutorial work in the same way , first browser answer 302 and than 200 and rows created.(

Comment: i resolved problem using this tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqDo2L-aSGw